# Why i am getting 2/4 rows when i nsert 1/2 row(s) in mySql

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am trying to save a file with some coordinates(lat, long) to an online database . I made a method as below. I read the file as string from an external storage and i split it to the end as an `latitude arrayList` and `longitude arrayList`. Afterwards i make a insert statment to the db. It works fine, but for exampe if i have one coordinate(x, y) in the file i get double in the db (1 row(x, y) and 2 row(x, y)), and if i have 2 points i get 4 rows in db! - I tried for many hours to find out where i did wrong. I simply stuck in this! - Any help is very appreciated, Thanks

```
private void fileToDataBase() {
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

        if (myFile().isEmpty()) {
            boolean delete = (new File(path, fileName)).delete();
            if(delete) {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            String[] latLngReplaced = myFile().replace("\n", ",").split(",");

            List<String> lats = new ArrayList<>(); 
            List<String> lngs = new ArrayList<>(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < latLngReplaced .length; i++) {  
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    lats.add(latLngErstatt[i]); 
                } else {
                    lngs.add(latLngErstatt[i]); 
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < lats.size() && j < lngs.size(); i++, j++) {

                Coordinate c = new Coordinate (lats.get(i), lngs.get(j));

                String in = "INSERT INTO coordinate(latitude, longitude) VALUES (" + c.getLatitude() + "," + c.getLongitude() + ")";

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("test", in));
                new AsyncTaskSendFila(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show a sample input file and how the resulting relation in the database should look like.

Comment: example: in my file 32.1212, 56.2332 and after sending to db it will be:       1 32.1212 56.2332                                                                                       2 32.1212 56.2332      (1 and 2 are id columns) have you any idea why this mutation? i want to be: 1 32.1212 56.2332

Comment: iI want it to become: 1 32.1212 56.2332

Comment: could you provide a longer input field? The odd lines are longitudes and the evens are latitudes, am I correct?

Comment: yes you are correct. lats list contains latitudes(even lines) and lngs list contains longitudes (odd lines).

Comment: you are using latLngReplaced .length to calculate the length in for loop, but from where you are getting this variable latLngErstatt?

Comment: sorry! latLngErstatt = latLngReplaced (translated to english).

Comment: For two values, you mentioned 4 records are created. Which pattern is same 1 and 3 or 1 and 2?

Comment: 1 and 2 same so 3 and 4 same . Example in the file: 1.point: 2.3, 2.5 and 2.point: 3.1, 5.4. To the db it'll be: 1 2.3 2.5 - 2 2.3 2.5 - 3 3.1 5.4 - 4 3.1 5.4 and normally is: 1 2.3 2.5 - 2 3.1 5.4 - hope you can help me!

Comment: Why do you have the following for-loop then?
*for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < lats.size() && j < lngs.size(); i++, j++)*

Comment: The 1. for-loop is to put latitudes and longitudes separately in a list. And the 2. for-loop  is to traverse the both list at the same time to get the elements and assign them to an object type Coordinate. the for-loops are different, i insert the values to my db-table from the 2. one.

Comment: After this AsyncTaskSendFila what is happening exactly?

Comment: once try logging the values of lats and longs array. If it is coming perfectly then there should be a problem in the way it is getting inserted in db

Comment: Totally agree. Now I know that you may get double when you write to a db (i think..). I'll try to delete the duplicates from the db. thanks for your support.

Comment: Hope you will resolve this..

Comment: just want to say that i found the problem and i resolved it. My problem was  i used a double code to insert values into a db :( , therefore i got duplicates values. I just delete one and everything is fine now. Thanks again for your response.